# Ruby on Rails testing XML validity

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to write a test for the validity of an XML file (EML) using its schema file within a Rails application. The test looks like this at the moment:

```
  test "eml is valid" do
    #load the xml library
    require 'libxml'
    # generate eml
    get :show, {:id => Dataset.first.id, :format => :eml}
    # load schema
    schema = LibXML::XML::Schema.new("/path/to/eml.xsd")
    # load file
    document = LibXML::XML::Document.file("here_the_eml_file_to_check.eml")
    # validate the file against the schema
    result = document.validate_schema(schema) do |message,flag|
      log.debug(message)
      puts message
    end
  end
```

The validation of the file itselfe works like charm when I do it by hand in irb. But my problem here in the test is how do I get the generated XML in the test as a file that I can put into the variable file so I can use it in the validation process?

Best Regards Claas